# Excel is inserting address into existing cell content problem

Tags: microsoft-excel, editing

Excel 2003. A schedule template used for years has never had this issue until the new user started and I can't reproduce the error because we never see it happen, only that it HAS.

Cells have content like 'ABC0012' or 'DEF3452' These are entered by typing, pasting, dragging, any number of ways, as they represent scheduled events.

THE PROBLEM: 
the discovery is made that what used to be 'ABC0012' is now 'ABC+Q14070012' or 'DEF3452' is now 'DEF+L16023452'

It seems to be inserting a cell address in the middle of the cell content.
there is no preceding equal sign which might explain address insertion, but it certainly acts like that.
AND it is always found later and never noticed when it occurs, so far.

Any key combination that might explain this? Or setting?

I neglected to mention, there are two macros on the sheet.

Worksheet_SelectionChange which checks if the active column is X and if it is, recalculates X2

and

Worksheet_Before_DoubleClick which does a lookup based upon the cell content and displays sales history based on that content in a form. Nothing is written to cells in either macro.

Thanks

Comment: Are there any macros or scripts in the sheet?

Comment: Yes, I apologize for not noting it, I edited the question, thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like he may be clicking other cells while he types or hitting the arrow keys.  I haven't been able to replicate this in a normal cell, but if I'm named range manager (ctrl+F3) and I type "ABC" then click Q1407 then type "0012 I get (or any other place within excel where you are selecting a range, like pivot wizard or graph wizard):

```
=ABC+Sheet1!$Q$14070012
```

Its a little different, but it is the same principle.  Using some parts of Excel it will automatically add "+" and the cell you clicked into what you are typing.  Also, is this user using Excel 2007 or 2010? Because I think ABC0012 is actually a valid cell name in those programs, so that could be problematic too.

Comment: Thanks, Excel2003. And what you describe in the named range manager behavior, it acts like. However there is no'=' preceding which normally causes the insertion of an range address.

Comment: Is it possible this user is erasing the "="?  If it were an invalid formula it would  throw an error and they would probably delete that.

Comment: I actually this this was the explanation, although the user denied it.